# Powershell- NewAcceptedDomain Command is not working in not working in visual studio. But it works fine in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run this powershell command from visual studio. 
My command is

```
add-pssnapin microsoft.exchange.management.powershell.snapin; New-accepteddomain –name domain123.com –domainname domain123.com
```

It always give me an error. 
The error is:

`"The term 'New-AcceptedDomain' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."`

But when i tried this command in powershell it works fine. But every time when i had try to run this command from my code it gives me error that i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the Exchange snapin is 64-bit therefore it is not available to the 32-bit PowerShell engine hosted in the 32-bit devenv.exe (Visual Studio) process. From the Nuget Package Manager console, execute:

```
Get-PSSnapin -Registered
```

To see if the Exchange snapin shows up.

Comment: I ran this command in nuget package manager console and found following result:

PM> Get-PSSnapin -Registered


Name        : WDeploySnapin3.0
PSVersion   : 2.0
Description : This is a PowerShell snap-in that contains cmdlets for managing Microsoft Web Deployment infrastructure.

I don't know what's this mean.. Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: That sort of confirms that the Exchange snapin is not available in this 32-bit PowerShell host.  You should be able to work around this with a job e.g. `$job = Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost {add-pssnapin microsoft.exchange.management.powershell.snapin; New-accepteddomain –name domain123.com –domainname domain123.com} -AsJob; Wait-Job $job; Receive-Job $job`.  This does require that VS is running as admin/elevated.  The job process that is used is 64-bit by default.

Comment: From my c# code it seems like it is working fine. But when i checked in powershell no domain were created with this command. 
Also i did try this command on powershell but it give me some permisssion related errors like "active directory operation failed on. The supplied credential for "domain/user" is invalid".

Comment: Loading that snapin by itself is not a supported method of managing Exchange.  It was designed to work with remote management sessions, using RBAC to control permission roles and a proxy account to do the actual updates.  To do this properly, you'll also need to connect to a management session on an Exchange server, so you have the equivalent of an Exchange Management Shell.  A simpler solution is to use remote management sessions via implicit remoting (import-possession), or directly (invoke-command).

Comment: I am new to use powershell. I don't have any experience to working with it. Please provide me some code samples. If possible please provide me all commands to sort this out.